# JavaFX ignoring backgrounds and fontweights

Tags: css, javafx, background

I am in the process of learning basic Java and JavaFX.  I am trying to apply certain styles to a simple program.  I have successfully connected the CSS and SOME styles work and others are ignored.  I am especially having an issue with -fx-background-color and -fx-font-weight, thusly.  The CSS is as follows:

```
.label{
-fx-font-size: 16px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
-fx-font-family: Tarazedi;
-fx-text-fill: #FF9900;    
}

#h1bar {
-fx-text-fill: #000000;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian, #000000, 1, 0, 1, 1 );
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( to right,
                             rgba(255, 153, 0, 1) 0px,
                             rgba(255, 153, 0, 1) 16px,
                             rgba(171, 153, 0, 0.67) 32px,
                             rgba(171, 153, 0, 0.67) 480px,
                             rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.33) 720px,
                             rgba(255, 153, 0, 0) 960px
                           );
-fx-padding: 4px;
-fx-background-radius: 16px;
}
```

The Java is as follows:

```
    primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome to tarazedi.com!");                      // Define window and title bar.
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();                                         // Create a GridPane

    grid.setHgap(16);                                                       // Set 10px gridlines.
    grid.setVgap(16);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(32, 32, 32, 32));                            // TRBL padding.

    Label scenetitle = new Label("\uf0a3  Welcome to tarazedi.com!");
    scenetitle.setId("h1bar");
    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

    Label pw = new Label("Password:");
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

    PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
    grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

    Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
    HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
    hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

    final Text actiontarget = new Text();
    grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
        actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 400);                                // Grid is the root node.
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);                                           // Display it.
    scene.getStylesheets().add(VictorSheckelsFX.class.getResource("VictorStyle.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.show();
```

The expected behavior would cause the header bar to look roughly like the orange bars on my site: http://victorsheckels.com/. Instead I have solid orange bars, no dropshadow, and no boldness on my font.  The font size, family, and color are WAI as are the padding and radius.

Comment: If you are on Java 8 you might try to set the CSS logger  `com.sun.javafx.Logging.getCSSLogger()` to display al messages. Can also be done via a logging properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages instead of pixels. JavaFX does not support non-percentage stops as reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176139)

For example:

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right,
rgba(255, 153, 0, 1) 0%,
rgba(255, 153, 0, 1) 1.6%,
rgba(171, 153, 0, 0.67) 3.3%,
rgba(171, 153, 0, 0.67) 50%,
rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.33) 75%,
rgba(255, 153, 0, 0) 100%);
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolves the background-color situation.  :)

Comment: The font-weight and the dropshadow seem also to work, right? I can clearly see a difference when removing them

Comment: I see no visible difference either way. Nor does it change when I move them to another element.

Comment: Ok, this is strange. Here is how it looks when removing the font-weight [normal](https://imgur.com/KZOhAVj) and when setting it to bold [bold](https://imgur.com/sJuvBO8)